# ^G appears on my NERDTree

Tags: plugin-nerdtree, vim8

I am building my personal and little distro of vim. I've just installed few plugins using this installer:

## The vimrc file

```
" encoding
set encoding=utf-8

" Tabs and spaces
set expandtab
set shiftwidth=4
set smarttab
set softtabstop=4
set tabstop=4

" NerdTree configuration
nnoremap <leader>n :NERDTreeFocus<CR>
nnoremap <C-n> :NERDTree<CR>
nnoremap <C-t> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nnoremap <C-f> :NERDTreeFind<CR>

let g:NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable = '▸'
let g:NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible = '▾'
```

## The installer.sh file

```
# NERDTree
rm -rf ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree
git clone https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree.git ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree
vim -u NONE -c "helptags ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/nerdtree/doc" -c q


# vim-airline
rm -rf ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/vim-airline
git clone https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline.git ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/vim-airline
vim -u NONE -c "helptags ~/.vim/pack/vendor/start/vim-airline/doc" -c q



cp vimrc ~/.vimrc
```

The strange thing is that files appears with a prefix and a suffix `^G`. I've tried to change encoding:

[image: ^G on my NERDTRee]

Comment: I've added that line as first line of vimrc file but the behavior is the same

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue just adding `syntax enable` to my `.vimrc` file.